# Why is Ruby CSV file reading very slow?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a fairly large CSV file, with 4 Million records with 375 fields, that needs to be processed.
I'm using the RUBY CSV library to read this file and it is very slow. I thought PHP CSV file processing was slow but comparing the two reads PHP is is more then 100 times faster. I'm not sure if I'm doing something dumb or this is just the reality of RUBY not being optimized for this type of batch processing. I set up simple test pgms to get comparative times in both RUBY and PHP. All I do is read, no writing, no building of big arrays, and break out of the CSV read loops after processing 50,000 records. Has anyone else experienced this performance issue?

I'm running locally on a MAC with 4gig of memory, running OS X 10.6.8 and Ruby 1.8.7.

The Ruby process takes 497 seconds to simply read 50,000 records, the PHP process runs in 4 seconds which is not a typo, it's more then 100 times faster. FYI - I had code in the loops to print out data values to make sure that each of the processes was actually reading the files and bringing data back.

This is the Ruby Code:

```
require('time')
require('csv')
x=0
t1=Time.new
CSV.foreach(pathfile) do |row|
  x += 1
  if x > 50000 then break end
end
t2 = Time.new
puts " Time to read the file was #{t2-t1} seconds"
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
$t1=time();
$fpiData = fopen($pathdile,'r') or die("can not open input file ");
$seqno=0;
while($inrec = fgetcsv($fpiData,0,',','"')) {
    if ($seqno > 50000) break;
    $seqno++;
}
fclose($fpiData) or die("can not close input data file");
$t2=time();
$t3=$t2-$t1;
echo "Start time is $t1 - end time is $t2 - Time to Process was " . $t3 . "\n";
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Upgrade your Ruby first. 1.8.7 had a slow CSV, plus, compared to today's Ruby v2.0, it's dog-slow.

Comment: Mike, I'm trying to find out if anyone else is experiencing this performance issue and if they have have then been able to resolve it? As Tin Man indicated it could be related to my version since it appears that 1.8.7 has a slow CSV library.

Answer (score 5):

You'll likely get a massive speed boost by simply updating to a current version of Ruby. in Version 1.9, [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) was integrated as Ruby's standard CSV library.

Check out [Chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) to manage your different Ruby versions.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv/) Gem, which has special options for handling huge files by reading data in chunks.

It also returns the CSV data as hashes, which can make it easier to insert or update the data in a database.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) is little bit overkill for this.

A long time ago I saw this question, and the reason for the slowness of the Ruby is that it loads the entire CSV file into the memory at once. I have seen some people overcome this issue by using the [IO class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html). For example take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/barmstrong/1323865) for its `self.perform(url)` method.

Comment: `CSV.foreach` reads one line at a time. See: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#label-A+Line+at+a+Time

Comment: lol I totally overlooked that. I was convinced that CSV.foreach is loading firstly everything to the memory.

Comment: For the 1.8.7 Ruby that Eric is using, it might be :)